# BPM null (most of the time) in Soundcloud /tracks requests

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm currently writing an web based application that allows users to mix Soundcloud songs. It's working really well at the moment and a lot of progress has been made so far. 
For DJ's, it's very important to be able to check the Beats Per Minute (BPM) of a song.

In the Soundcloud API, some songs are able to show their BPM's, others aren't... For example, when I try to read the data of my request in JavaScript, most of the times the BPM is **'null'**. For others, the BPM is shown correctly.

The information that we get from Soundcloud differs with every request. For example, when the BPM **IS** available, the response is:

```
<bpm type="float">124.0</bpm>
```

When the BPM is unavailable, the response is:

```
<bpm nil="true" />
```

Does anyone know what might be causing the problem? Why is Soundcloud not showing BPM's for all of its tracks?

Help would be appreciated! :-)

[Example request + response](https://snap.apigee.com/18VGMz7)

Answer (score 1):

That data is added by the user who uploaded the track. Some users don't add that info.